# C# Dependent dll is not getting copied to app folder

Tags: c#, dependencies, copy

I am creating new empty project in visual studio. Add my references(libraries) .dll files are not getting copied into root folder. I already have Copy Local to true. Is it possible to copy them programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you add references as dll files? Can you use nuget packages?

Comment: The one i am using is not in nuget. It use to be a small project (minihttpd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, reference add is - permanent relative links to files. You can:
1) Put dll in the shared folder
2) Make a folder for nuget and make nugets, if you want to centralize the dlls.
3) The most correct one without nuget is to put the files in the project(repository).

Answer (score 0):

You can add post build tasks to copy other files to the output folders.